# How can I access nested JSON variable in Karate fed from Gatling?

Tags: karate

I have a JSON File feeder which has JSON that is nested like:

```json
{
  "id": "X",
  "context": {
    "id": "Y"
  },
  "username": "Z"
}
```

And I can successfully access the `id` and `username` in my Karate file using: `#(__gatling.id)` etc. However, when I try and access `#(__gatling.context.id)` it comes up `null`.

Gatling has obviously parsed it into a Map but I'm unclear now how to access this variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are setting up the feeder data. Here is the example in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#feeders

```
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("someKey" -> "someValue"))
```

And then `#(__gatling.someKey)` would work. So try the Map (JSON) like this and it should work. And please use the new 1.0 RC stream as this is going to be released soon: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

If it still doesn't work, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: A stated the feeder is a JSON File Feeder - it's pointing to a file. Also as stated #(__gatling.id) works fine. However, nested call #(__gatling.context.id) does not. It simply comes back as "null".

Comment: @hawkini to be honest I have never used whatever a JSON file feeder is. it sounds like a Gatling-specific thing and it is quite likely Karate does not support it 100%. do you mind following the process above so that we can look at it ? or try to use another approach where you build an in-memory `Map` and that may work